# Why the same neural architecture works in Keras but not Tensorflow ( Leaf Classification )?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, kaggle

Recently I am playing the leaf classification problem in Kaggle. I have seen a notebook [Simple Keras 1D CNN + features split](https://www.kaggle.com/alexanderlazarev/leaf-classification/simple-keras-1d-cnn-features-split). But when I tried to construct the same model with Tensorflow, it generate very low accuracy and loss change little. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale,StandardScaler

#preparing data
train=pd.read_csv('E:\\DataAnalysis\\Kaggle\\leaf\\train.csv',sep=',')
test=pd.read_csv('E:\\DataAnalysis\\Kaggle\\leaf\\test.csv',sep=',')
subexp=pd.read_csv('E:/DataAnalysis/Kaggle/leaf/sample_submission.csv')

x_train=np.asarray(train.drop(['species','id'],axis=1),dtype=np.float32)
x_train=scale(x_train).reshape([990,64,3])
ids=list(subexp)[1:]
spec=np.asarray(train['species'])
y_train=np.asarray([[int(x==ids[i]) for i in range(len(ids))] for x in spec],dtype=np.float32)

drop=0.75
batch_size=16
max_epoch=10
iter_per_epoch=int(990/batch_size)
max_iter=int(max_epoch*iter_per_epoch)
features=192
keep_prob=0.75

#inputs, weights, and biases
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,64,3])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,99])

w={
    'w1':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1,3,512],dtype=tf.float32)),
    'wd1':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([64*512,2048],dtype=tf.float32)),
    'wd2':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2048,1024],dtype=tf.float32)),
    'wd3':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024,99],dtype=tf.float32))
}

b={
    'b1':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([512],dtype=tf.float32)),
    'bd1':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2048],dtype=tf.float32)),
    'bd2':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024],dtype=tf.float32)),
    'bd3':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([99],dtype=tf.float32))
}

#model.
def conv(x,we,bi):
    l1a=tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv1d(value=x,filters=we['w1'],stride=1,padding='SAME'))
    l1a=tf.reshape(tf.nn.bias_add(l1a,bi['b1']),[-1,64*512])

    l1=tf.nn.dropout(l1a,keep_prob=0.4)
    l2a=tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,we['wd1']),bi['bd1']))
    l3a=tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(l2a,we['wd2']),bi['bd2']))
    out=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(l3a,we['wd3']))

    return out

#optimizer and accuracy
out=conv(x,w,b)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=out,targets=y))
train_op=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(out, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

#train
with tf.Session() as sess :
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    step=0
    while step<max_iter :
        d =(step % iter_per_epoch)*batch_size
        batch_x=x_train[d:d+batch_size:1]
        batch_y=y_train[d:d+batch_size:1]
        sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={x: batch_x,y: batch_y})

        if step%10==0:
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y,})
            print("Iter: ", step,"  loss:",loss, "  accuracy:",acc)
        step+=1
    print('Training finished!')
```

The result is something like:

```
Iter:  0   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  10   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  20   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  30   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  40   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  50   loss: 0.698778   accuracy: 0.0625
Iter:  60   loss: 0.698778   accuracy: 0.0625
Iter:  70   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  80   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  90   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  100   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  110   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  120   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  130   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  140   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  150   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  160   loss: 0.69941   accuracy: 0.0
Iter:  170   loss: 0.698778   accuracy: 0.0625
......
```

But when using the same data and model in Keras, it indeed generate very good result.
code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Convolution1D, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=512, filter_length=1, input_shape=(64, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(99))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, nesterov=True, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=16)
```

result:

```
Epoch 1/5
990/990 [==============================] - 78s - loss: 4.3229 - acc: 0.1404          
Epoch 2/5
990/990 [==============================] - 76s - loss: 1.6020 - acc: 0.6384     
Epoch 3/5
990/990 [==============================] - 74s - loss: 0.2723 - acc: 0.9384     
Epoch 4/5
990/990 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 0.1061 - acc: 0.9758
```

By the way, keras uses Tensorflow backend. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple differences between both models, your TF model uses ADAM, while your Keras model uses SGD. The learning rates are different as well, and learning rate greatly affects model convergence.

The loss functions also don't match, the Keras model uses categorical cross-entropy, while the TF model is using sigmoid cross-entropy with logits (which usually is used for multilabel classification). Also sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits takes logits as input (real numbers), and you are giving it the output of a softmax function.

There are also differences in weight initialization, you are using truncated normal distribution for the TF model, while Keras by default uses glorot_uniform or uniform.

These differences are of course the reason why one model trains, and the other does not.

Comment: The softmax instead of logits is the most likely culprit here. All other differences might or might not prevent convergence, but this one is pretty sure to prevent it :)